# How to force compiler to compile same source file every time used in different shared libraries in cmake?

Tags: c++11, cmake, c++98

I have 3 `.cpp` files which are used in generation of 2 different shared libraries. One is compiled using c++98 and other using c++11.

compiler here creates an `.o` file (object file) only once for both shared libraries.
How to force compiler to compile all these 3 files every time in single pass?

PLEASE SUGGEST HOW TO DO THIS IN `CmakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I am already using add_library for my shared libraries and haven't used add_executables.

Comment: my flags are not overridden but .o file is being resued everytime here as source code is not changed but flags are changed .. that is the main issue

Comment: I meant the only difference between what you want and what the answer says is that you will use `add_library` instead of the `add_executable` in sakra's answer. The solution sets the compile flags for the targets (your two libraries, not your three source files) individually. The source files for each target is the same.

Comment: In `boost.build` it is quite easy, you make "obj" targets first which can reuse the same .cpp file, then convert "obj" to "exe". I don't know how to do it in cmake, sorry. https://github.com/cbeck88/strict-variant/blob/master/bench/Jamroot.jam#L63

Comment: @ChrisBeck Yup that's the problem here...

Comment: @spt025: maybe this is what you want? https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library hmm maybe not actually...

Comment: @spt025: please just try sarka's answer. You will find that two sets of .o files are generated from the same three source files, which is what the Makefile solution in your last question does. One set with the c++98 compiler flags and one set with the c++11 compiler flags. One of your library targets (the one whose `PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS` is set to c++98 compiler flags) will have the set of object files compiled with the c++98 compiler flags and the other will have those compiled with c++11. That I think is what you want.

Comment: I think you want either sakra's answer like aichao said, or you could try having two different output directories and try to get the object file created in two different places so that cmake doesn't reuse it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297518/cmake-working-with-multiple-output-configurations/2357060#2357060

Comment: What's the difference to the other question you just asked an hour before this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38897195/2799037 Oh and by the way: Why do you scream in your question?